# Scrapy + Splash (Docker) Issue

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash

I have scrapy and scrapy-splash set up on a AWS Ubuntu server. It works fine for a while, but after a few hours I'll start getting error messages like this;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1384, in _inlineCallbacks
result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 393, in throwExceptionIntoGe
nerator
     return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
 packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 43, in process_re
quest
defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError: Connection was refused by 
other side: 111: Connection refused.
```

I'll find that the splash process in docker has either terminated, or is unresponsive.

I've been running the splash process with;

```
sudo docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash
```

as per the scrapy-splash instructions.

I tried starting the process in a tmux shell to make sure the ssh connection is not interfering with the splah process, but no luck.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You should run the container with `--restart` and `-d` options. See the [documentation](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#hard-way) how to run Splash in production.

Comment: Thanks. I just stumbled upon this idea myself, googling around, but that is a great resource. I will just add for the next person... you can see why your docker processes failed with 'docker ps -a', and note that exit code 137 seems to be related to memory overuse. And what @Tomas was suggesting is to have docker automaticalky restart the process when it fails due to lack of memory.

Comment: Splash is not sending correct url. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63212796/why-is-scrapy-splash-not-sending-correct-url this. I need help.